# How does "shape" variable working under the hood?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm getting some course about swift. And I saw the following pice of code:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
        if isFaceUp {
            ZStack {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                Text("✈️").font(.largeTitle)
            }
        }
        else {
            shape.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is variable "shape" is used 3 times there, and we apply different properties on it. It shows like a 3 different objects on the screen. Does it mean that new copy of this variable is created each time a refer to it(in this scenarion)? Or does it work in some another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you posted from your tutorial was probably trying to make a point about modifiers and conditionals in a view. However, it was not well written. We avoid defining variables inside the body variable, and instead define them outside and call them from inside the view. This code is very confusing, and I am not sure why it was written that way. The more standard way of writing it would be:

```
struct ShapeView: View {
    
    let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if isFaceUp {
                VStack {
                    shape.fill().foregroundColor(.red)
                    shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                    Text("✈️").font(.largeTitle)
                }
            }
            else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code `let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)` defines a view as calling a `RoundedRectangle` returns a view. You can then use that view later, and, importantly, you can modify it.

This code:

```
ZStack {
    shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
    shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
    Text("✈️").font(.largeTitle)
}
```

actually returns 1 view made up of 3 views stacked on top of each other. You can see this clearly on the canvas if you change it to be:

```
VStack {
    shape.fill().foregroundColor(.red)
    shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
    Text("✈️").font(.largeTitle)
}
```

You can see that the canvas or simulator will now show a red rounded rectangle above a clear(will look white because of the background) rounded rectangle outlined in black, above the airplane.

If `isFaceUp` is `false`, you will simply see a black rounded rectangle XXXwhite background as there will be a clear rounded rectangle displayed that is invisible to usXXX. Add a color and you will see what I mean.

The upshot is, in SwiftUI, everything is eventually merged into 1 view.

p.s. I purposefully left out declaring `isFaceUp` as that brings in another set of issues. Just know that it would be declared as a bool outside of body as well, probably simply with `shape`

Comment: “We avoid defining variables inside the body variable”—defining local properties inside `body` is fine. If it wasn't fine, they wouldn't have added support for it in Swift 5.3 (it wasn't possible in Swift 5.1 when SwiftUI was introduced).

Comment: @robmayoff I agree it is allowed in the language, obviously. However, it can throw beginners off, and I believe can make the code more difficult to read, IMHO.

Comment: Actually it's best practice to avoid declaring variable in the body but in this case i think it's justified. You can't at least in Xcode 12.5 with iOS14 as a target add a `.fill()` and `.stroke()` on the same shape, basicaly he just avoided to write `RoundedRectangle` twice.

Comment: @DjallilElkebir exactly. I wasn't sure how far to go into the issue of `.fill()` and `.stroke()`, as I don't know where he saw the code, or what its point was.

Comment: @Yrb Thanks for your explanation. As far as I understand when we do something like `shape.fill()` or `shape.stroke()` it will take my original view `shape` and return new one with new property.

Comment: Exactly. It is the same with ANY view. You can write `Text"Hello World!"` you can then modify it like `Text"Hello World!".font(.largeTitle)`, and further still `Text"Hello World!".font(.largeTitle).bold()`. Some modifiers you can't stack like the `.fill()` and `.stroke()`. You will learn why in time. Last thing, the Order of modifiers matters. If you get an error, try changing the order. Also, changing the order will create different looks.

Comment: @ArtyomGusev yes, modifiers like `.fill()` and `.stroke()` will return a new type called `some View` and can only be applied on Shapes. 
If you use one of them on a shape like `RoundedRectangle` it will return `some View` so you can't apply another function that only works on shapes. In the code you posted basicaly he is creating multiple `RoundedRectangle` and apply a modifier to each.